# Viewpager fragment selector state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a viewpager where the user can tap a photo and the photo will take a 'highlighted' state.

I achieve the 'highlighted' state by setting a FrameLayout overlay above the image. The problem is when i swipe trough the pages the state is not only lost but it appears on non selected images.

This is my viewpager adapter:

```
public class ImageSliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

//Image ids from constants
private int[] Images = Constants.Images;


private int mCount = Images.length;

public ImageSliderAdapter$Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


// The displayed fragment for each position
@Override
public FragmentImageSlider getItem(int position) {

    return  FragmentImageSlider.newInstance(Images[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
 }
}
```

And this is the fragment that the viewpager returns:

```
public class FragmentImageSlider extends Fragment {

//Image resource id to show
int imageResourceId;

//Image view of the pic displayed
ImageView image;

// View to indicate highlighted images
View highliteView;


public static FragmentImageSlider newInstance(int imageResourceId){
    FragmentImageSlider f = new FragmentImageSlider();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putInt("image", imageResourceId);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getArguments() !=null) {

        //get image resource id from extras
        imageResourceId = getArguments().getInt("image");
    }

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.displayLayout, null);


    image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    highliteView = root.findViewById(R.id.highliteView);


    image.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

    //When the image is clicked, toggle the highlighted state
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //toggle state
            //this view has a selector and changes when selected
            highliteView.setSelected(!highliteView.isSelected());
        }
    });
    return root;
 }
}
```

So my question is, how can i keep the highlighted state?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `visibility` of your `highlight view` instead of `selected state`.

By default set the `visibility` of highlight view as `GONE` and when the image is selected change it to `visible`.

```
highliteView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// when the image is clicked show the highlighted view
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       highliteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FragmentPagerAdapter document](view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible),

> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though **its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible**

The `view` maybe reloaded from default layout when it go out of the view, that's why the highlight state is lost.

You should keep the highlight state in your `Fragment`:

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment{
    //variable to keep the state
    private boolean highlight;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //rest of your other code

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               highliteView.setSelected(!highliteView.isSelected());

               //set the highlight state when clicked
               highlight = !highliteView.isSelected();
           }
        });
        return root;
    }

    //set the view state to the image view
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        highliteView.setSelected(highlight);
    }
}
```